# FlatList not scrolling on Android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, redux

I am new to react native and while going through a tutorial , I got stuck with scrolling of FlatList. On the tutorial with the same code I can see the list is scrolling. I am using Android emulator.

```
class LibraryList extends Component {


    renderItem = ({ item }) => (
         <ListItem library={item} />
      );

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.libraries);
        return (

            <FlatList
                data={this.props.libraries}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor={library => library.id.toString()}
        />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { libraries: state.libraries };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

Comment: could you provide a running code: https://snack.expo.io? [`ListItem`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html) doesn't have a `library` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Try by wrapping your `FlatList` with the empty `View` having `flex` is `1`.

So your render method code will be like below code:

```
 render() {
        console.log(this.props.libraries);
        return (
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.libraries}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor={library => library.id.toString()}
              />
         </View>
        );
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Try by applying flex to FlatList itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code block (example , change this self code)

```
 renderFlatList() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.database}
        ListHeaderComponent={() => this.renderAddFeedScool()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderItem(item)}
      />
    );
  }    
render() {
    return (
      <View style={_styles.container}>
        {this.props.database.length > 0 ? (
          this.renderFlatList()
        ) : (
          <Text>Loading</Text>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

Styles..
container: {
flex: 1,
},
```

Full code : https://github.com/VB10/Nativer/blob/master/src/view/tab/school/index.tsx

And look at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist
and :)  final solution use native-base list component i think exactly solution https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-def-headref

Good work.